# Getting .val() of select tag .on('change') not working when using "nice-select" jQuery plugin to style the select tag

Tags: jquery, events, select, plugins

I have a normal select tag in html

```
<div>
 <select name="sort-by" id="sort-by" class="nice-select show-menu-arrow">
  <option value="sortby">Sort By..</option>
  <option value="Section">Section</option>
  <option value="Alphabetical">Alphabetical</option>
  <option value="Time">Time</option>
</select>
```

And the following code in jQuery to send an AJAX request (using the .val() of the select tag) when either of the following events happen in my form: a select tag changes, a checkbox is clicked, or a character is entered into the search bar.

```
$("#filter-words select,  #filter-words input[type='checkbox'], #filter-words input[type='text']").on('change keyup', function() {

var sortBy = $("#filter-words select#sort-by").val();
```

This code worked fine until I used the jQuery plugin "nice-select" 
(http://hernansartorio.com/jquery-nice-select/)

When using this plugin, the .on('change') event doesn't work on the select tag. The reason for this (I believe) is that, according to the nice-select page (link above), when using the plugin, this:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Some option</option>
  <option value="2">Another option</option>
  <option value="3" disabled>A disabled option</option>
  <option value="4">Potato</option>
</select>
```

becomes this:

```
<div class="nice-select">
  <span class="current">Some option</span>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="option selected">Some option</li>
    <li class="option">Another option</li>
    <li class="option disabled">A disabled option</li>
    <li class="option">Potato</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

SO MY QUESTION IS:

How can I get around this problem? According to this question ([Change function stop working when I add Dropkick or MultiSelect plugins to style Select elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479342/change-function-stop-working-when-i-add-dropkick-or-multiselect-plugins-to-style)) the select tag plugins DropKick and MultiSelect have this documented, but I can't seem to find any documentation on this problem for nice-select.

Comment: Provide MCVE replicating your issue

Comment: Does the `#filter-words` element really surround the select?... try this code instead: `var sortBy = $("#sort-by").val();`

Answer (score 6):

<del>It appears that nice-select is copying the original select using jQuery's `.html()` function</del>, so any bindings attached to the original select will be broken. You can get around this by using [delegated event binding](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)...

It needs to point to a wrapper around the select. For example

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <select id="sort-by">
    ...
  </select>
</div>
```

then use the following code to bind to the select:

```
$(".wrapper").on('change', 'select', function() {
  var sortBy = $("#sort-by").val();
  // do whatever with the value
});
```

Comment: But the `select` element is removed from the DOM if i understand it correctly. EDIT: just checking source code, it is hidden not removed, and click on LI element trigger change event, so i guess just delegating it wouldn't fix it

Comment: You're right, it's not copying using the `.html()` function... then I'm not sure why the binding is failing.

Answer (score 3):

you just need to use the same functions which are in the library file.

```
    $(document).on("click", ".nice-select .option:not(.disabled)", function (t) {
                                            
    var s = $(this),
    n = s.closest(".nice-select");
                                            
    console.log(s.data("value"));
})
```

This is just for the click event. You might also take the keydown events from the library

Comment: thats some skills bro, gotta love jquery.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

Basically what I did was listen for a DOM change inside the div wrapping the select using this code:

```
var observeDOM = (function(){
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver,
    eventListenerSupported = window.addEventListener;

return function(obj, callback){
    if( MutationObserver ){
        // define a new observer
        var obs = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer){
            if( mutations[0].addedNodes.length || mutations[0].removedNodes.length )
                callback();
        });
        // have the observer observe foo for changes in children
        obs.observe( obj, { childList:true, subtree:true });
    }
    else if( eventListenerSupported ){
        obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', callback, false);
        obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', callback, false);
    }
}
})();

// Observe a specific DOM element:
observeDOM( document.getElementById('wrapper'), function(){ 
  $hidden_input = $("input[name='hidden_checkbox']");

  if( $hidden_input.prop('checked') === true ) {
    $hidden_input.click();
  } else {
    $hidden_input.click();
  }
});
```

and when a change was detected inside of the div with an id of wrapper I checked a checkbox I included in the html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="hidden_checkbox" value="hidden_checkbox" id="hidden_checkbox"  />
```

This code in the jQuery runs $("input[type='checkbox']).on('change')

```
$("#filter-words select,  #filter-words input[type='checkbox'], #filter-words input[type='text']").on('change keyup', function() {

var sortBy = $("#filter-words select#sort-by").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello guys I found a soluction.

I updated the nice-select.min.js file

On the line 130

change this

```
  $dropdown.prev('select').val($option.data('value')).trigger('change');
```

by:

```
 $dropdown.prev('select').val($option.data('value')).trigger('click');
 $dropdown.toggleClass('open');
```

It worked for me, I hope that this work for you.

Comment: I think I love you man. Spent 2 hours trying to fix this in React.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to use

```
$(document).on("change",".yourclass-on-select", function () {

});
```

Instead of

```
$(".yourclass-on-select").on("change", function () {

});
```

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

Javier-Your code change definitely saved me alot of time!

The only thing you should mention is that after editing: nice-select.min.js file

That solution enables you to use "onClick" now to get the value instead of "onChange" which for some reason, one works and the other doesn't (The onclick does work). Handy hack too if your working in reactJS where it's like , now you can just use .

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding this snippet in my JS file because I didn't feel like changing the original `nice-select` files:

```
$(document).on('change', '.styled-select', function (e) {
    e.target.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
});
```

So what happens here is I listen to the `change` event that library triggers and initiate the proper `change` event which does work. This might cause double events in some cases and it would of course be better if the library would do this properly, but they don't seem to accept pull requests on their GitHub project...